# Ionic InAppBrowser and routes

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working on an ionic project.

I need to use the InAppBrowser plugin to display a website.
But depending on which page I am, I need to change the view to an Ionic page.

```js
export class HomePage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser, public platform: Platform) {
        var url = "https://helloworld.com";
        var browser = inAppBrowser.create(url, '_blank', {
            zoom: 'no',
            location: 'no'
        });

        platform.ready().then(() => {
            browser.show();

            browser.on('loadstart').subscribe((e) => {
                var navCtlr = this.navCtrl;
                var scriptUrlParam = "window.addEventListener(\"click\",function(e){var href=e.target.getAttribute(\"href\");if(href){location.href=href+\"?source=mobapp\";e.preventDefault();}});";

                var url = e.url;
                if (url.indexOf("scanner") !== -1) {
                    alert("Page Scanner");
                    navCtrl.push(QrcodePage);
                }

                browser.insertCSS({
                    code: "#mobileMenu{display:block!important;}"
                });
                browser.executeScript({
                    code: scriptUrlParam
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**navCtrl.push(QrcodePage);** is supposed to redirect  me to the QR Code page. But it doesn't work.

I know I am on the right page because `alert("Page Scanner");` is working.

Have anyone occurred this probleme already ?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you `hide()` the InAppBrowser before navigating?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Add [`browser.hide()`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#inappbrowserhide) before `navCtrl.push`

Comment: let me try this

Comment: Can you explain me how this works ?

Comment: I assume InAppBrowser is an overlay over the WebView, so the navigation might work but be invisible because it's covered by the InAppBrowser.

Comment: Thanks, sounds good to me